# Spacy spans for parts of tokens

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

*EDIT:*

I update this question due to the recent development of the pipeline for the upcoming spaCy 2.0 release. ([described here](https://alpha.spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components))

the new `_` property is designed to carry data for custom pipeline components. My input text contains highlighted parts, for example

> This is an example text **document this is an example text document.
>   This is an example text document this is an example** text document.
>   This is an example text document this is an e**xamp**le text document.

I would like to use spans to keep track of which parts of this document are highlighted. I chose this example to show that the highlighting may span only parts of a token, but also even more than a sentence. As described im my original question below, internally the span seems to be capable of storing intervals on character-level however e.g. the slicing works on token-index-level.

I imagine the new more user friendly pipeline may help achieving this.

---

*The original question:*

As far as I understand the model of spaCy there are documents with tokens and spans. I think I have a pretty decent understanding of tokens since this is a concept that I came over in different nlp libs. However, spans I don't really understand.

Spans are for example used to yield sentences from a document. Also, if you slice a document the return will be of type span.

Internally a span consists, apart from other attributes, of

```
start
start_char
end
end_char
```

where start and end denote the index of the starting and ending token of the span whereas start_char and end_char denote the starting and ending character of the span.

the start_char and end_char attributes are not exposed by the constructor.

My question is: Are spans supposed to be strictly a grouping of tokens or can they be used for denoting everything from a single character of a token to multiple sentences?

If they are not the according data structure, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Spans only deal with whole tokens, `start_char` and `end_char` are *derived* from the token values. Why do you need to have part of a token in a span? Can you give a specific example? Half a word can't be a noun...

Comment: I have additional meta information on the text. An example would be text that is highlighted. It has no limitations on characters, tokens or sentences.

Comment: Well, spans aren't designed to cover parts of tokens, so they won't help you.  You can specify annotations with arbitrary character positions - see [here](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/entity-recognition) - but if it doesn't match a token boundary it's considered an error and discarded. What do you want to do with your metadata? Predict where it would be on new text? **Please give a specific example.**

Comment: There are many examples where character spans make sense, for example when analysing compound words in German, where a token can be split into the individial compounds, plus glue characters, plus morphological endings, sometimes in several ways. For many languages morphological prefixes and suffixes would be something that would make useful spans. Named entities for chemical terms can sometimes go over several tokens, but then the important parts need to get split inside what Spacy is one token, so this could be a character span covering several tokens but not aligned with token boundaries.